# Questions Regarding the Applicability of Green's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

1)Can Green's theorem only be applied to plane surfaces or can they be applied to all surfaces with a differentiable equation of the bounding curve?

2)Which is more fundamental,Green's theorem or Stokes'theorem since I managed to derive Green's theorem to be a special case of Stokes' in which the surface being operated upon was a plane one.

3)Would I be right in saying that Stokes' theorem can be easily applied to all curves with a differentiable equation(i.e. Does it have any limitations) ?

Comment: It's not clear what you'er asking about (3) .

Answer (score 0):

1) In the way Green's Theorem is generally stated, it is only valid to plane surfaces. To more general surfaces, you must first transform the integral to a integral on a region of the plane. Of course, in this case, the bounding curve would be different...

2) Certainly, Stokes' Theorem is more general than Green's> Stokes is applicable to much more general surfaces, of any dimension.

I don't understant what you mean in 3.

Comment: Thank you, and in (3) i was trying to ask the limitations(if any) of Stokes' theorem